# How to duplicate object with independent modifiers, using Python

Tags: python, modifiers

I'd like to replicate copying (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and pasting (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) an object using Python, i.e. the copy should be identical, yet completely independent of the original (i.e., if I change something about the original, the copy should not be affected). While this is easy to achieve for some properties, by copying the object data or calling `bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(type='SELECTED_OBJECTS', object=True, obdata=True, material=True, animation=True, obdata_animation=True)`, I did not find a way yet to do this for modifiers, such as geometry nodes. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Nice question! I think it should be reported, if it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What exactly would you like to have reported?

Comment: try `bpy.ops.node.copy_geometry_node_group_assign()`

Comment: @relaxed Thanks for the hint! Would you mind elaborating a little? The documentation of `bpy.ops.node.copy_geometry_node_group_assign` is a little sparse, as of now.

Comment: I don't have much more either. It´s is the same operator as in the middle of the header of Geometry Node Editor (files icon) where you can copy the active geometry node group and assign it to the active modifier in one step to make it a separate node group. Similar to the "New/Add" button in most data block menus. [https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/templates/data_block.html#data-block-menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @relaxed, I found a solution that works for me, for the moment. However, be aware that there might be other data blocks (apart from node setups, particle settings and textures) that need to be copied as well.

```py
def create_duplicate(object_: bpy.types.Object, 
                     duplicate_name: str, 
                     target_collection: bpy.types.Collection) -> bpy.types.Object:
    duplicate = object_.copy()
    duplicate.data = object_.data.copy()
    duplicate.name = duplicate_name
    
    target_collection.objects.link(duplicate)
    
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = duplicate
    duplicate.select_set(True)

    bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(object=True, 
                                    obdata=True, 
                                    material=True, 
                                    animation=True, 
                                    obdata_animation=True)
    
    for particle_system in duplicate.particle_systems:
        particle_system.settings = particle_system.settings.copy()

    for modifier in duplicate.modifiers:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_set_active(modifier=modifier.name)
        
        if modifier.type == "NODES":
            bpy.ops.node.copy_geometry_node_group_assign()
        elif hasattr(modifier, "texture"):
            modifier.texture = modifier.texture.copy()
            
    return duplicate
```